# Attached event to element inside Google Maps API (v3) Infowindow fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with multiple markers.

When the user clicks on a marker an Infowindow opens with some content (that I get from some JSON array), I want the user to be able to click on an element here and call a function after that.

However, my problem is that this function is being called X times, where X is the number of markers on the map.

This is how I'm getting my marker data:

```
 function setupMarkers(mapObject) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api/events",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var event = {
                    id: response[i].eventsid,
                    markerid: "markerEvent" + i,
                    latitude: response[i].latitude,
                    longitude: response[i].longitude,
                    // ...
                };

                var eventMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(event.latitude, event.longitude),
                    map: mapObject
                });

                var template = $('#marker-template').html();
                var rendered = Mustache.render(template, event);
                makeInfoWindow(eventMarker, mapObject, infoWindow, rendered);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the template I'm using:

```
<script id="marker-template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  <div class='info-window'>
    <h2><a href='#' id='{{markerid}}' data-eventid='{{id}}'>{{title}}</a></h2>
    <p>{{attending}} user(s) are going</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

And this is `makeInfoWindow`

```
function makeInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(content);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
        $("a[id^=markerEvent]").click(function(e) {
            var id = document.getElementById(e.target.id).dataset.eventid;

            // prints the id X times (where X is the number of markers on the map)
            console.log(id);

            // doSomething(id);
        });
    });
}
```

I suspect my problem is that all markers share a single instance of InfoWindow, so the event is being fired for each marker because I create them inside my for loop - but is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, nevermind - I'm stupid.
Just move

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    $("a[id^=markerEvent]").click(function (e) {
      var id = document.getElementById(e.target.id).dataset.eventid;
      // doSomething(id);
    });
});
```

out of `makeInfoWindow` and just put it below

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

on `setupMarkers`